# Input won't save to a text file after the first run, won't append or overwrite after the first run

Tags: java, netbeans, text-files, filewriter

I am using netbeans windows 11, I just want to save input entered to a text file without it getting overwritten ideally. It works fine on the first run, text file gets created, input gets written to the file, but any entries after that don't get saved and neither does the file get overwritten with the new entry.

```
        if (!newUsername.getText().equals("") && (!newPass.getText().equals(""))){
            // Check to see if the Username.txt file already exists
            File file = new File("Username.txt");
            if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Handle the exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         FileWriter fileWriter = null;
    try {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);

        // Write the newUsername variable information to the text file
        fileWriter.write(newUsername.getText());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle the exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // Close the FileWriter object
        if (fileWriter != null) {
            try {
                fileWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Handle the exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    }
            
            
            new Splash().setVisible(true);
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            dispose();
        }else {
            feedback.setText("Fields can't be blank");
        }
        
        
    }
```

I didn't try anything else I mean I asked google Bard, it said it might be a file permissions issue but that doesnt make sense because like I said it does work fine on the first run, file gets created gets written as expected, so can't be a  file permissions issue i think.

Comment: It is only writing the file _if (!file.exists())_.

Comment: BTW there is no need to call `createNewFile` - the file will be created by `FileWriter` if needed (and possible/allowed)  **And** you must work on correct indentation of code - this would eventually even make the error easier to find/see (most IDEs have a format function to do that for you...)

Comment: Yeah I thought so too, I don't know why bard made me add that, and the indentation is bad cuz I did copy and paste some code snippets, sorry :3

Comment: Huge amount of redundant boilerplate code there. Also, how are you going to use a file that will consist of *one continuous string*?

Comment: The purpose of using the text file is as an alternative to MySQL, Oracle etc, because im not allowed to use them. It's a university project. So I want to use text files to store usernames and passwords of users who will register and then login using those credentials